# How to extract text using pdftotext.exe with bold,italics identification

Tags: vb6

i have been using pdftotext.exe to extract text from pdf. The text accuracy was good by using this. But the problem was i can't able to identify bold and italics text.
How can i identify the extracted text was bold or italic?

I had tried some other plugin like CSWTestingReflow, PDF parser etc..but for better text accuracy i was go with pdftotext.exe

Any idea would be appreciable..

Code:

```
objdos.ExecuteCommand """" & App.Path & "\pdftotext.exe" & """" & " -layout " & """" & sReadPDF & "_Text.pdf" & """"
''objdos.ExecuteCommand """" & App.Path & "\pdftotext.exe" & """" & " " & """" & sReadPDF & "_Text.pdf" & """"
    If fso.FileExists(sReadPDF & "_Text.txt") = True Then
                'Read the text file
                Set adoStreamOut = New ADODB.Stream
                'adoStreamOut.Charset = "utf-8"
                adoStreamOut.Charset = "us-ascii"
                If adoStreamOut.State Then adoStreamOut.Close
                adoStreamOut.Open
                adoStreamOut.LoadFromFile Replace(sReadPDF, ".pdf", "") & "_Text.txt"
                sText = adoStreamOut.ReadText
    End If

 DoEvents
sText = Trim(sText)
sText = Trim(Replace(sText, Chr(12), ""))
sText = Trim(Replace(sText, "." & vbCrLf, ".|||"))
sText = Trim(Replace(sText, "?" & vbCrLf, "?|||"))
sText = Trim(Replace(sText, "--" & vbCrLf, "||||||"))
sText = Trim(Replace(sText, "-" & vbCrLf, "-|||"))
sText = Trim(Replace(sText, vbCrLf, " "))
sText = Trim(Replace(sText, ".|||", "." & vbCrLf))
sText = Trim(Replace(sText, "?|||", "?" & vbCrLf))
sText = Trim(Replace(sText, "-|||", ""))
sText = Trim(Replace(sText, "||||||", "--"))
sText = Trim(Replace(sText, "--", "—"))
Do
 sText = Trim(Replace(sText, "  ", " "))
Loop Until InStr(sText, "  ") = False
```

Comment: i dont know pdftotext.exe but can you post (a link to) a pdf document, and the resulting text pdftotxt.exe gives ? does pdftotext.exe only give plain text or does it show some layout characters as well (like for example rtf) ?

Comment: I also am not familiar with pdftotext, it appears to be a component of Xpdf (which is open source) available from [http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/home.html](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/home.html). On this Xpdf page ([http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/portsntools.html](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/portsntools.html)), there is a link to another tool based on Xpdf, pdftohtml ([http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/](http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/)).  Perhaps pdftohtml will provide you with the functionality you're looking for?

Comment: It shows layout characters using the property -layout..

Comment: Thaks MarkL . i vl check pdftohtml