# Text Extraction with bold and italics identification

Tags: vb6

I want to extract text from pdf with bold and italics identifiction. for example bold letters need t be extracted like this.<b>TEST</b> and italics must be enclosed like <i> test </i>
 Currently i am using texttopdf.exe to extract text..the accuracy was good.but not able to identify bold italics.

any one have another idea or the same pdftoexe having the feature?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract text using pdftotext.exe with bold,italics identification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23486463/how-to-extract-text-using-pdftotext-exe-with-bold-italics-identification)

Comment: In the duplicate question also there is no answer

Comment: posting the same question more than once isnt the way to get your answer faster. if you want your question to get more attention and maybe a faster answer, then you can consider offering a bounty .. lets continue in your other post of this question as that shows more info